# Is the 83(b) election deadline inclusive of the start date?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, 83b-election

In 2014 I early exercised 10,000 unvested options and filed an 83(b) with the IRS. The stock from the exercise transferred on January 1st, 2014. I called the IRS and confirmed they have the 83(b) on file, but said the timestamp in the system was January 31st, 2014.

While I'm certain I mailed this via Certified USPS mail prior to the deadline, neither the IRS or I have record of the postmarked envelop date.

The wording in section 83:

> Under § 83(b)(2), an election made under § 83(b) must be made in
> accordance with the regulations thereunder and must be filed with the Internal Revenue
> Service no later than 30 days after the date that the property is transferred to the
> service provider.

Does this mean the cutoff is:

January 30th (30 days starting on January 1st)

OR

January 31st (30 days starting on January 2nd)?